# Copia de arrays con aux, resetea a 0 las celdas

Tags: java, array

> Hola. Tengo un método que pretende sumar el contenido de las celdas de dos arreglos de longitud diferente. Para evitar los OutBoundsException, trato de igualar las length de los dos array que pretendo sumar. Averiguo el length del mayor y se lo asigno a una variable "size" y después creo un objeto auxiliar con el tamaño de size. A continuación  asigno el contenido de las celdas del array de menor tamaño al nuevo array Aux que ya tiene el length adecuado. Hasta ahí todo bien. El problema aparece cuando asigno el objeto Aux que ya tiene el length adecuado y las celdas adecuadas al obj2 original. Me respeta solo la primera celda  las demás a 0;

```
public static EnteroEnorme sumar(EnteroEnorme obj1, EnteroEnorme obj2) {

    String str="";

    int size=obj1.Entero.length>obj2.Entero.length ? obj1.Entero.length : obj2.Entero.length; //variable que almacena el mayor length

    if(obj1.Entero.length>obj2.Entero.length) {


        EnteroEnorme aux=new EnteroEnorme(new int[size]);

        for(int i=0; i<obj2.Entero.length; i++) {
            aux.Entero[i]=obj2.Entero[i];

            obj2=aux; //HASTA AQUÍ FUNCIONA BIEN. AQUI AL ASIGNAR AUX AL OBJ2, ME PONE EL CONTENIDO DE LAS CELDAS A 0, A EXCEPCION DE LA PRIMERA CELDA..

    }
}


   if(obj2.Entero.length>obj1.Entero.length) {


        EnteroEnorme aux=new EnteroEnorme(new int[size]);

        for(int i=0; i<obj1.Entero.length; i++) {
            aux.Entero[i]=obj1.Entero[i];
            obj1=aux;
            }   
    }



    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {

        str+=obj1.Entero[i] + obj2.Entero[i];

    }


    return new EnteroEnorme(str);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada vez que publico algo al poco me doy cuenta del error. Hay que sacar las asignaciones al del Aux del ciclo for